# How to create page for user?

Tags: users, author, profiles

I'm using author.php to display all user and their info. I would like to add a separate page like this : domain.com/users/user_name/ABOUT

Is there a way to add a page (ABOUT) and retrieve info of that user in that page ?

Comment: This may be possible with rewrite rule endpoints

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't just want to make the "author archive" a page and list them all on the page with a shortcode ? If that's an option, simply put your single author template in author.php

[Author templates - Template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Which_Template_File_is_Used.3F)

If not, you could take your current template (that you've put in author.php) and move it to archive.php with a conditional tag, only showing your authors if the query is for post type authors .

[Conditional tags - A post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#a-post-type)

But any way you do it, I don't think you will get the permalink structure you're asking for:

> domain.com/users/user_name/ABOUT

But rather :
All users (using the archive page to list all authors): domain.com/archive.php
Single user (or about-page): domain.com/author.php

If you instead were to use a simple page and a shortcode you could get:
All authors: domain.com/users
Single user: domain.com/author.php

Comment: the OP already has author archives, it's the addition of a new sub section at `../about` that lists info about that author rather than their post archive that's being asked about